# Why am i getting an error with this line of code, when the logic is used else where and it has no issues?

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

Im trying to write Conways Game of Life, and for some reason 1 line of code comes up with an error even though it's same logic has been used elsewhere in the code and is fine.

Code:

```
origin = [
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

c = origin
current_cycle = 1
while current_cycle < (x_cycle + 1):
    for i in origin:
        for j in i:
            count = 0
            x = i #X-Coordinate
            y = j #Y-Coordinate

elif y == 0:
                if x == 0: #Top Left Corner
                    if c[x + 1][j] == 1:
                        count += 1
                    if c[x][j + 1] == 1:
                        count += 1
                    if c[x + 1][j + 1]:
                        count += 1
                elif x == c[-1][-1]:  #Top Right Corner
                    if c[x - 1][y] == 1:
                        count += 1
                    if c[x-1][y + 1] == 1:
                        count += 1
                    if c[x][y + 1] == 1:
                        count += 1
                else: #Top Left to Top Right
                    if c[x-1][y] == 1:
                        count += 1
                    if c[x-1][y+1] == 1:
                        count += 1
                    if c[x][y+1] == 1:
                        count += 1
                    if c[x+1][y+1] == 1:
                        count += 1
                    if c[x+1][y] == y:
                        count += 1
```

The error I am getting is:

```
line 111, in gameoflife
    if c[x-1][y] == 1:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Any help/advice is appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Where does the `elif y == 0:` part come from?

Comment: `i` and `j` are not coordinates. `i` is a row, and `j` is a value in the row. If you want coordinates, it should be `for i in range(len(origin)):` and `for j in range(len(origin[i])):`

Comment: Note that `c = origin` doesn't make a copy of the grid. If you modify `c[x][y]`, you'll also be modifying `origin`. You should probably make a deep copy of origin.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. you have helped a lot here. The thing with the co ordinates was very useful to know, and i ended up just changing my code to use origin[x][y] rather than c[x][y]. Thanks a bunch!!